# how to save iptables rules permanently?

Tags: iptables

I want to keep some iptables rules permanence, so I just only add the rules mannually:

```
/sbin/iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 -j QUEUE
```

I am sure that it work, because I could see it after executing "iptalbes -vnL".
Unfortunately, I find it disappear without rebooting or restarting iptables after an hour or so. because I could not see it after executing "iptables -vnL".

so I have to look into this problem.

first of all, I am sure there is no one executing command like "iptables -F",

and then I find one log in /var/log/message:

```
Dec 18 10:10:50 zt_21_23 kernel: ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

I find this is a kernel behavior completely after google. someone says iptables would rebuilt the rules, but he don't tell me the triggering condition. and I check the iptables configuration file(/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config), but I could not find any configuration item that could make iptables rebuilt the rules.

and I have to add the rules at set intervals by using crontab if I want to keep it permanace.

until now, my questions are:

```
1. how to stop iptables rebuilt?
2. when would iptables rebuilt? and what is the triggering condition?
3. which rule would be reloaded when iptables rebuilt? and where these rules save?
```

could you help me?

PS.

modifying /etc/sysconfig/iptables, or using iptables-save and iptables-restore could work, the rules still disappear after an hour or so.

and I am using linux(2.6.18-308.24.1.el5 x86_64).

Comment: You would get better answers to this on SuperUser.

Comment: thank you, I have asked, but I still get no answer.

Comment: Please provide the link to your Q on SU, I'll answer there.